# Why do interface aliases behave differently in function parameters?

Tags: php, oop

Interface aliases don't seem to work in PHP the way I would expect.

Is this an undocumented feature that I should avoid in production code? Or is there a best practice for aliasing interfaces in PHP?

All the PHP documentation seems to say is that you can create aliases, and doesn't specify anything unique about interfaces:

> "All versions of PHP that support namespaces support three kinds of
>   aliasing or importing: aliasing a class name, aliasing an interface
>   name, and aliasing a namespace name."
>   [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php)

```
<?php namespace RootNamespace;

use ChildNamespace\ISomeInterface as ISomeInterface;
use ChildNamespace\ImplementationOfSomeInterface as ImplementationOfSomeInterface;

class App {

    public static function SomeFunc(ISomeInterface $i) {
        return $i;
    }

    public static function SomeOtherFunc(ChildNamespace\ISomeInterface $i) {
        return $i;
    }
}

$i = new ImplementationOfSomeInterface();

// Throws Catchable fatal saying that ImplementationOfSomeInterface != ISomeInterface
App::SomeFunc($i); 

// Works as 'expected'
App:SomeOtherFunc($i);
```

[Additional fake code]

```
<?php namespace RootNamespace\ChildNamespace;

interface ISomeInterface {
    public function RequiredFunc($param);
}

class ImplementationOfSomeInterface implements ISomeInterface {
    public function RequiredFunc($param) {
        return $param;
    }
}
```

For the record, I noticed this behavior on PHP version: PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.11

Comment: Can you show the code of `ImplementationOfSomeInterface` ?

Comment: Updated -- I can't show the actual code that triggered this inconsistency as it's private but this *should* reproduce the issue. I'll verify that this code triggers it later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static function SomeOtherFunc(ChildNamespace\ISomeInterface $i)
```

This type refers to `\RootNamespace\ChildNamespace\ISomeInterface`, and NOT `\Childnamespace\ISomeInterface`.